# TYPO3 Extension made with Extension Builder doesn't show any data

Tags: typo3

I have tried to make an extension with the Extension Builder. But it doesn't show any data.
As default, it shoes the table header and the links for Make new record.

I have included the static template and I am sure the Storage Folder is correct. I have checked it in the TypoSfript Object Browser and it is correct. In the storage folder I have made 2 records in my extesnion, but the extension doesn't show any data.

I have also remembered to clear the cache both in the backend and in the Install tool.

What can I do to debug further?

Comment: Is the storage folder configured correctly in TypoScript? If you create records in the frontend, do those show up? On which page are they stored?

Comment: Did you use plugin name correctly in typoscript?
did you include your typoscript setting by template->root->info/modify and include tab ?

Comment: Yes, every other created content shows correctly. The static template is included. The storage folder pid 32 is correctly set and I can see in TypoScript Object Browser that it is set to 32.

Comment: In 0815 extension builder you do not set the storage folder by typoscript. You set it in the frontend plugin. That confuses me a bit.

Comment: That didn't change anything. Do you know if I can debug the MySQL quiries somehow to she what it says?